# Chinese/Japanes characters are loading as ???? to MariaDB database in AWS RDS using pentaho

Tags: mariadb, pentaho

While loading Chinese/Japanese characters into MariaDB of AWS. Data is loading as ???? even after changing charset to 'UTF8'/'utf8mb4' and collation as 'utf8_general_ci'/'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'. I am using pentaho community edition to load data.

However, when I load data to textfile as output, its working fine using Pentaho in AWS EC2 machine.

I've changed the variables also like below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOCuk.png)

In my local database, using Pentaho, I am loading successfully into MySQL database. However, with the same settings, its not working in MariaDB of AWS RDS.

Please suggest any other changes do I need to make any changes here.

Many thanks in advance for your help here.

With regards,
Rohith

Comment: Can you please change all the parameter you have mentioned in your image to 'utf8mb4' and also update [collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci & collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci]  . After complete update restart the DB. If its still not work then run [SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci] this command.

Comment: Hi Runa, thanks for your replay. It didnt work still. I've tried as you said above.

Comment: can you please run SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character%';
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%character%'; and show the output.

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored